# What's the most efficient high input voltage / low power converter?

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, efficiency

I have a design goal of creating an AC/DC converter whose maximum input power will be 1W @ 230V.
The main issue is that most designs I've found are no more than 80% efficient (in best case senarios).
What topologies could I explore that might be able to provide very high efficiency?
Since isolation from the mains is not necessary, I'm thinking of looking into Tottem Pole PFC converts (although they seem highly efficient only at high wattages) or a flyback with GaN HEMTs.

Anyone have any suggestion for high efficiency sub-watt designs?

Comment: So what's the output voltage? And current?

Comment: Nominal output voltage would be 12V @ 73-80mA

Comment: What about other constraints? If a theoretical answer achieves 99.9% efficiency but costs a million, will it be a good answer, or do you have some reasonable efficiency or budget in mind?

Comment: A 1 watt supply with 80% efficiency is only going to dissipate 200 milliwatts. This should not cause heating problems in most applications. Why do you need higher efficiency for such a small power supply? If you give us more information, we may be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: @Justme I don't see many questions with explicit budget constraints. If one of the possible answers is excessively expensive, then I would expect it to be compared with a cheaper one to explain the tradeoffs.

Comment: @ZagElectroBat Synchronous rectification can buy you perhaps another 5% over diode rectification. So you just *might* be able to hit somewhere around 85-90% that way. You should look at existing AC-DC IC converters featuring synchronous rectification control units and see what you can track down that way. That should provide some benchmarks that you can include in your question to improve it. You can also add your own commentary about your reactions to what you uncover on that topic. All of that improves the question.

Comment: rather than use a converter, maybe the old technique of using a bjt/mosfet to switch off when the input voltage exceeds a given value. Being half wave rectified AC the output is pulsed with a width dependent on the actual input voltage. A suitably sized capacitor smooths this out. The loss would be in the input rectifier and the switching device. Fairchild had a device that did this, but it is now obsoleted.

Comment: Does the output volts have to be regulated against line variations? does it have to be load regulated? Is galvanic isolation needed for this job?

Comment: The output needs to be load regulated -- Synchronous rectification on the secondary side might indeed help. I've been looking into no-opto flybacks, but for very low power they don't seem to be making a huge difference